# Watershed algorithm in Python

Tags: python, watershed

I am trying to use watershed algorithm to separate overlapping cells.

This is my image, and when I used ImageJ, it works quite well as below:
[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTFIe.png) [ImageJ result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcVws.png)

However, when I used skimage watershed in python, some cells are missing (e.g. top right and bottom right). And I found it's because  `feature.peak_local_max` didn't detect local maxima in these regions:
[python output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXHVN.png)

This is the code I used in python. I would like to know how can I get the same results as ImageJ. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
distance = ndi.distance_transform_edt(img)

local_max_coords = feature.peak_local_max(distance, min_distance=7,labels = ndi.label(img)[0])
local_max_mask = np.zeros(distance.shape, dtype=bool)
local_max_mask[tuple(local_max_coords.T)] = True
markers = measure.label(local_max_mask)
labels = watershed(-distance, markers, mask=img,watershed_line=True)
```

Comment: What library is being used here to calculate the watershed?